# How to implement a subprocess.Popen with both live logging and a timeout option?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-multithreading

My goal is to implement a Python 3 method that will support running a system command (using subprocess) following a few requirements:

- Running long lasting commands
- Live logging of both stdout and stderr
- Enforcing a timeout to stop the command if it fails to complete on time

In order to support live logging, I have used 2 threads which handles both stdout and stderr outputs.

My challenge is to enforce the timeout on the threads and the subprocess process.

My attempt to implement the timeout using a signal handler, seems to freeze the interpreter as soon as the handler is called.

What's wrong with my implementation ?

Is there any other way to implement my requirements?

Here is my current implementation attempt:

```
def run_live_output(cmd, timeout=900, **kwargs):
    full_output = StringIO()

    def log_popen_pipe(p, log_errors=False):
        while p.poll() is None:
            output = ''
            if log_errors:
                output = p.stderr.readline()
                log.warning(f"{output}")
            else:
                output = p.stdout.readline()
                log.info(f"{output}")
            full_output.write(output)

        if p.poll():
            log.error(f"{cmd}\n{p.stderr.readline()}")

    class MyTimeout(Exception):
        pass

    def handler(signum, frame):
        log.info(f"Signal handler called with signal {signum}")
        raise MyTimeout

    with subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True, 
        **kwargs
    ) as sp:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:
                try:
                    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
                    signal.alarm(timeout)
                    r1 = pool.submit(log_popen_pipe, sp)
                    r2 = pool.submit(log_popen_pipe, sp, log_errors=True)
                    r1.result()
                    r2.result()
                except MyTimeout:
                    log.info(f"Timed out - Killing the threads and process")
                    pool.shutdown(wait=True)
                    sp.kill()
                except Exception as e:
                    log.info(f"{e}")

    return full_output.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 0):

Q-1) My attempt to implement the timeout using a signal handler, seems to freeze the interpreter as soon as the handler is called, What's wrong with my implementation ?

A-1) No your signal handler not freezing, There is freezing but not in the signal handler, signal handler is fine. Your main thread blocked (frozen) when you call `pool.shutdown(wait=True)`. Because your subprocess is still running and you do `while p.poll() is None:` in the `log_popen_pipe` func. That's why your main thread will not continue until `log_popen_pipe` finished.

To solve this issue, we need to remove `pool.shutdown(wait=True)` and then  call the `sp.terminate()`. I suggest you to use `sp.terminate()` instead `sp.kill()` because `sp.kill()` will send `SIGKILL` signal which is not preferred until you really need it. In addition that, end of the `with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:` statement,  `pool.shutdown(wait=True)` will be called and this will not block you if `log_popen_pipe` func ended.

In your case `log_popen_pipe` func will finished if subprocess finished when we do `sp.terminate()`.

Q-2) Is there any other way to implement my requirements?

A-2) Yes there is, you can use `Timer` class from `threading` library. Timer class will create 1 thread and this thread will wait for `timeout` seconds and end of the timeout seconds, this created thread will call `sp.terminate` func

Here is the code:

```
from io import StringIO
import signal,subprocess
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import logging as log
from threading import Timer
log.root.setLevel(log.INFO)

def run_live_output(cmd, timeout=900, **kwargs):
    full_output = StringIO()

    def log_popen_pipe(p, log_errors=False):
        while p.poll() is None:
            output = ''
            if log_errors:
                output = p.stderr.readline()
                log.warning(f"{output}")
            else:
                output = p.stdout.readline()
                log.info(f"{output}")
            full_output.write(output)

        if p.poll()!=None:
            log.error(f"subprocess finished, {cmd}\n{p.stdout.readline()}")


    with subprocess.Popen(
         cmd,
         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
         stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
         universal_newlines=True, 
         **kwargs
    ) as sp:

        Timer(timeout,sp.terminate).start()

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:
            try:
                r1 = pool.submit(log_popen_pipe, sp)
                r2 = pool.submit(log_popen_pipe, sp, log_errors=True)
                r1.result()
                r2.result()

            except Exception as e:
                log.info(f"{e}")

    return full_output.getvalue()


run_live_output(["python3","...."],timeout=4)
```

By the way `p.poll()` will return the `returncode` of the terminated subprocess. If you want to get output of successfully terminated subprocess, you need to use `if p.poll()==0` 0 generally means subprocess successfully terminated